# Sign in with apple missing App Name in the permission message

Tags: ios, swift, auth0, sign-in-with-apple

I am trying to `Sign in with Apple` using `Auth0`.
But the permission message shows my app name as `null`

This is the permission message.

> Do you want to sign in to `null` with you Apple ID "myAppleId@email.com"?

The logo of my app is showing correctly. It is the app name that is showing `null`

Where do I set the app name?

Edit: Here is how it looks -

[image]

Comment: did you set app name in General --> Display Name ?

Comment: no need to set name anywhere. it will take automatically with project name.

Comment: @iNiravKotecha I'm experiencing the same issue, do you know why auth0 failed to retrieve the project name to be shown in permission message view?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma did happen to solve this issue? if yes, would you tell me how? thanks.

Comment: @LuthfiRahman are you using Auth0?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma yes, I do, same as you. That's why I left comment in your thread.

Comment: @LuthfiRahman - check out my answer. See if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If trying with Auth0, you can go with the following way to solve this problem.
**Step 1.**

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    // Create the authorization request
    let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()

    // Set scopes
    request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]

    // Setup a controller to display the authorization flow
    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])

    // Set delegates to handle the flow response.
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self

    // Action
    controller.performRequests()
}
```

**Step 2** 
Implement the delegate method and get apple's authorization code there.

```
extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController,
                                 didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
            // Success
            guard let authorizationCode = appleIDCredential.authorizationCode,
                let authCode = String(data: authorizationCode, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    print("Problem with the authorizationCode")
                    return
            }
         }
    }
}
```

**Step 3** 
Now you use this `authCode` to login to the Auth0.

```
func appleSignin(with authCode: String)  {
    Auth0.authentication().tokenExchange(withAppleAuthorizationCode: authCode)
        .start { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let credentials):
            //LoginSucces
            case .failure(let error):
                //Issue with login.
            }
    }
}
```

In this method, you don't show the webview like for other login methods with Auth0.
I had posted this on Auth0 Community (the issue that I posted here), and one of their engineers replied me to approach it this way.
Check this out for more info [Sign in with Apple - Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ios-swift-siwa)

Comment: so, you don't use sign in with apple in auth0 Lock (universal login view)?

Comment: No, like I said, the Auth0 engineer in the community asked me to use the other ways since the Webview has these kind of problems.

Comment: okay, understood. Is there any simple way to recreate the other UI objects in universal login view when you use this way?

Comment: Dont think so.. For me, the only UI is apple's ui for login, in this case.

Comment: https://community.auth0.com/t/sign-in-with-apple-returns-app-name-as-null/37343/4
here is the link to the discussion on Auth0 community

Comment: in my case I need all the UI objects on universal login, including other social ID login button, such as `Log In With Google`.

Comment: In my case, I have all the login options in native. and then use `Auth0.webAuth()` to show the login based on which method the user selects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name and email while sending the request as requestedscopes.

Function to create a request using ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider and initialize a controller ASAuthorizationController to perform the request.

```
@objc func handleAppleIdRequest() {
let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
authorizationController.delegate = selfauthorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

Below function is called after successful Sign In.

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as?  ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user 
let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName 
let email = appleIDCredential.email
print(“User id is \(userIdentifier) \n Full Name is \(String(describing: fullName)) \n Email id is \(String(describing: email))”) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was an incorrectly pointed federated sign in domain, and the solution provided didnt work for me, so here is my solution:

Go to developer.apple.com

Navigate to "Certificates, Identifiers, & Profiles"
Select "Identifiers" from the left sidebar
Select "Services IDs" from the right drop down box
Select "Configure" for "sign in with apple"
Add the correct Cognito domain name under the website URLs section

The name that will show up for "null" is whatever the name of the services ID is now

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Auth0 but I was facing this issue and it took me an hour to find out where that thing is set!

It was showing a dummy string I had put once, a long time ago. Now I wanted to replace it but couldn't find out whether that was in the app, code, build script, app setting, developer settings, or where the hell!

I wanted to change this:

[image]

It turned out that when you go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles (at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list) you can actually click on that blue thing on the top right of IDentifiers and that's bringing a whole list of things!

**Why the hell Apple thought that putting a sub-menu over there is better than having a nested list in the left menu bar is beyond my imagination!**

[image]

So from here, you go to **Service IDs** and change that thingy! If it's null and you can set it.  The direct link to that Shangri-la page is: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/serviceId